What is DBX/Native HTTP connections in Delphi DataSnap?
I'm busy trying to make an API using DataSnap in Delphi and I need to decide between TDSRESTWebDispatcher and TDSHTTPWebDispatcher.
I read that the HTTP dispatcher also supports DBX/Native HTTP connections, but what is that? What does that mean for my use case of creating an API using DataSnap in Delphi?
